# Print an address of function in C++, g++/clang++ vs vc++ , who is right?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang++, reinterpret-cast, static-cast

Consider following simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
void foo() { }
int main() {
    std::cout<<static_cast<void*>(foo);
}
```

It compiles fine on `VC++` but `g++` & `clang++` gives compilation errors.

See live demo [here](http://rextester.com/HPFFD48636) ( `VC++` )

See live demo [here](http://rextester.com/XXYIB76210) ( `clang++` )

See live demo [here](http://rextester.com/PAADP7292) ( `g++` )

Diagnostics given by `g++` & `clang++`:

```
source_file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
source_file.cpp:4:38: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘void()’ to type ‘void*’
     std::cout<<static_cast<void*>(foo);
                                  ^
```

So, the question is which compiler is right here according to C++ standard ? I think behaviour of `g++` & `clang++` is correct here. I know that I should use `reinterpret_cast` here instead of `static_cast`. Is this bug in `VC++` compiler ? If answer depends on the specific standard of C++ then also I am curious to know about it.

Comment: foo decays into function pointer !!!

Comment: If you want correctness on MSVC, make sure to use MSVC14.1 with the recently added `/permissive-`. It's also more generally referred to MSVC thse days instead of VC++.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GCC and Clang are correct, because the conversion you are attempting to perform is not among those that can be performed by `static_cast`. Those conversions are enumerated in [expr.static.cast]. I will briefly summarize them with references to paragraphs in that section:

- Base to derived reference conversion (p2)
- Conversion to xvalue of reference-compatible type (p3)
- Conversion using the operand for direct-initialization (p4)
- Conversion to void (p6)
- Inverse of standard conversion sequence (p7)
- Integer/enum conversions (p9, p10)
- Base to derived pointer conversion (p11)
- Derived to base pointer-to-member conversion (p12)
- Void pointer to object pointer conversion (p13)

Furthermore, p5 says:

> No other conversion shall be performed explicitly using a `static_cast`.

The conversion of a function or function pointer to `void*` is not among the conversions listed.

In particular, direct-initialization does not apply since there is no standard conversion from function pointer to `void*`. According to [conv.ptr]/2:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv* `T`,” where `T` is an object type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer
>   to *cv* `void`”. The result of converting a non-null pointer value of a pointer to object type to a “pointer to
>   *cv* `void`” represents the address of the same byte in memory as the original pointer value. The null pointer
>   value is converted to the null pointer value of the destination type.

Note that this only covers object pointers, not function pointers.

Answer (score 1):

From [this pointers-to-void reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_void):

> Pointer to **object** of any type can be implicitly converted to pointer to `void`

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

And [from this function reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/functions):

> Functions are not objects

That seem to indicate that pointers to functions simply can not be converted to `void*`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that which compiler is right. So, it would be better if you come up with standard citations !!!

Comment: @Destructor Updated answer