# C++: How to store various member functions of different classes for later use

Tags: c++, c++11

thanks in advance for your support.

I'm using C++11 and I want to store public member functions of some classes for later use as callback functions; e.g. I want to store some functions that matches this template: **void(classname::*)(void)**. As far as I know, I have to store their objects too, It's fine. For example:

```
// PSEUDO CODE
class A {
    public:
    void myfunc() {}
}myobj;

class B {
    public:
    void myfunc2() {}
}myobj2;

/* storing */
mystorageclass storage;
storage.push(&myobj, &A::myfunc);
storage.push(&myobj2, &B::myfunc2);

/* call them back */
(storage[0].object->*(storage[0].callback))();
(storage[1].object->*(storage[1].callback))();
```

Is there any safe and generic way to do that? Actually I've found a way, but I'm not sure how much it's portable across processors or compilers.

```
//test.cpp - compiled with: g++ test.cpp -o test -std=c++11
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
    public:
    void myfunc() { std::cout << "Test A::myfunc()" << std::endl; }
}myobj;

class B {
    public:
    void myfunc2() { std::cout << "Test B::myfunc2()" << std::endl; }
}myobj2;

struct Callback {
    void* object;
    void(* method)(void*);
};

std::vector<Callback> callbackList;

template<typename FunctionPtr>
void add(void* object, FunctionPtr fptr) {
    Callback cb;
    cb.object = object;
    cb.method = (void(*)(void*))(*(void**)(&fptr));
    callbackList.push_back(cb);
}

int main() {
    //add to list for later use
    add(&myobj, &A::myfunc);
    add(&myobj2, &B::myfunc2);

    //call them back
    callbackList[0].method(callbackList[0].object);
    callbackList[1].method(callbackList[1].object);
}
```

And another way to do; I feel this is much more safe:

```
//test2.cpp - compiled with: g++ test2.cpp -o test2 -std=c++11
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
    public:
    void myfunc() { std::cout << "Test A::myfunc()" << std::endl; }
}myobj;

class B {
    public:
    void myfunc2() { std::cout << "Test B::myfunc2()" << std::endl; }
}myobj2;

struct Callback {
    struct A;
    A* object;
    void(A::* method)();
    void call() {
        (object->*method)();
    }
};

std::vector<Callback> callbackList;

template<typename FunctionPtr>
void add(void* object, FunctionPtr fptr) {
    Callback cb;
    cb.object = (Callback::A*)object;
    cb.method = (void(Callback::A::*)())(fptr);
    callbackList.push_back(cb);
}

int main() {
    //add to list for later use
    add(&myobj, &A::myfunc);
    add(&myobj2, &B::myfunc2);

    //call them back
    callbackList[0].call();
    callbackList[1].call();
}
```

Does these usages are safe? Or what do you suggest instead of these.
Thanks.

Comment: Use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: Have you tried to compile the second version? It should not compile. You can't call a member function using a `void*`.

Comment: I've tried, but these are the best results I got. @CaptainObvlious

Comment: Both works @RSahu

Comment: Follow the examples in the link I gave you. Start by using `std::function` for something small and trivial just to get used to it. Once you're familiar with it try it applying it to your code.

Comment: Do you want to store the functions in a file or have the operating system load them in later?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thank you for your interest, problem solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem with the second version**

In the line

```
cb.method = (void(*)(void*))(*(void**)(&fptr));
```

you are casting a function pointer to `void**`. I am not sure that is supported by the standard. My guess is it is not. I know casting a function pointer to `void*` is not supported by the standard. See [Print an address of function in C++, g++/clang++ vs vc++ , who is rght?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511868/print-an-address-of-function-in-c-g-clang-vs-vc-who-is-rght) for details.

And then, you proceed to use:

```
callbackList[1].method(callbackList[1].object);
```

This relies on conventions used by a compiler to pass `this` as the first hidden argument when calling a member function of a class. There is no guarantee that the method is used by all compilers. The standard does not explicitly state that.

**Problem with the third/last version**

You are using:

```
cb.object = (Callback::A*)object;
cb.method = (void(Callback::A::*)())(fptr);
```

regardless of whether the object type is `A` or `B`. This is cause for undefined behavior. The standard does not support casting of an object pointer to any old pointer type.

**A Cleaner Version**

Use a base class for `Callback`.

```
struct Callback {
   virtual ~Callback() = 0;
   virtual void call() = 0;
};
```

Then, use a class template for the real `Callback`s.

```
template <typename T>
struct RealCallback : public Callback
{
   RealCallback(T* obj, void (T::*m)(void)) : object(obj), method(m) {}

   virtual void call()
   {
      (object->*method)();
   }

   T* object;
   void (T::*method)();
};
```

With this, you won't be able to store a list of `Callback` objects but you can store a list of `shared_ptr<Callback>`s.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Callback>> callbackList;
```

Here's a complete program that does not rely on any ugly casts and works perfectly.

```
//test.cpp - compiled with: g++ test.cpp -o test -std=c++11
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class A {
    public:
    void myfunc() { std::cout << "Test A::myfunc() on " << this << std::endl; }
}myobj;

class B {
    public:
    void myfunc2() { std::cout << "Test B::myfunc2() on " << this << std::endl; }
}myobj2;

struct Callback {
   virtual void call() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct RealCallback : public Callback
{
   RealCallback(T* obj, void (T::*m)(void)) : object(obj), method(m) {}

   virtual void call()
   {
      (object->*method)();
   }

   T* object;
   void (T::*method)();
};

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Callback>> callbackList;

template<typename T>
void add(T* object, void (T::*fptr)()) {
    RealCallback<T>* cb = new RealCallback<T>(object, fptr);
    callbackList.push_back(std::shared_ptr<Callback>(cb));
}

int main() {
    //add to list for later use
    add(&myobj, &A::myfunc);
    add(&myobj2, &B::myfunc2);

    std::cout << "myobj: " << &myobj << std::endl;
    std::cout << "myobj2: " << &myobj2 << std::endl;

    //call them back
    callbackList[0]->call();
    callbackList[1]->call();
}
```

**Update, in response to comment by Yakk**

I think Yakk's suggestion makes sense. You can remove the classes `Callback` and `RealCallback` with

```
using Callback = std::function<void()>;

std::vector<Callback> callbackList;
```

Then, `add` can be simplified to:

```
template<class T>
void add(T* object, void(T::*ptr)()) {
   callbackList.push_back([object, ptr]{ (object->*ptr)();});
}
```

With those changes, `main` needs to be slightly updated to:

```
int main() {
    //add to list for later use
    add(&myobj, &A::myfunc);
    add(&myobj2, &B::myfunc2);

    std::cout << "myobj: " << &myobj << std::endl;
    std::cout << "myobj2: " << &myobj2 << std::endl;

    // Updated. Can't use callbackList[0]->call();

    //call them back
    callbackList[0]();
    callbackList[1]();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and brilliant answer, I'm appreciate that to see very well improved version of my solution. I was thinking how to jump and store those kind of 'type variable' pointers. I've thought about template variables that C++14 offers, but I really did not want to use C++14 for portability reasons. Thank you, that 'abstract base class' storing method is really clever.

Comment: @ÖmerGöktaş, you're welcome. Please note that I added a `virtual` destructor to the base class.

Comment: I don't get why you'd go off and implement a weak version of `std::function` instead of ... just using `std::function`?

Comment: @Yakk, your suggestion definitely simplifies user code.

Comment: And it doesn't involve a heap allocation.  ;)

Comment: @Yakk, I think use of `std::function` and lambda functions is not the first things jump to a new user's mind. Just guessing.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `Callback` with `std::function<void()>`.

Replace `add` with

```
template<class T, class R, class U>
void add(T* object, R(U::*ptr)()) {
  Callback cb = [object, ptr]{ object->ptr(); };
  callbackList.push_back(cb);
  // or just
  // callbackList.push_back([object, ptr]{ object->ptr(); });
}
```

note that this supports passing in pointers-to-parent member functions, and callbacks that do not return void and discarding the result.

`std::function` stores a generic "call this later".  You pass a type compatible with the return value, and args compatible with what you want to call later, in the template signature argument of `std::function<signature>`.  In this case, `<void()>`.

Comment: `callbackList.push_back(std::bind(ptr, object));`?

Comment: @MooingDuck Why would you use `std::bind`?  I mean, ever?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `std::function` or `std::bind`both of them need to keep the reference to the instance:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
class MyClass
{
    int _value;
public:
    MyClass(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    void food()
    {
        cout << "Foo is doing something whit value: " << _value << endl;
    }
    void bar()
    {
        cout << "Bar is doing something whit value: " << _value << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{

    MyClass* c1 = new MyClass(1);
    MyClass* c2 = new MyClass(2);

    cout << "Using 'std::function':" << endl;

    std::function<void(MyClass&)> food = &MyClass::food;
    std::function<void(MyClass&)> bar = &MyClass::bar;

    food(*c1);
    bar(*c1);
    food(*c2);
    bar(*c2);


    cout << "Using 'std::bind':" << endl;

    auto foodBind = std::bind(&MyClass::food, std::placeholders::_1);
    auto barBind = std::bind(&MyClass::bar, std::placeholders::_1);

    foodBind(*c1);
    barBind(*c1);
    foodBind(*c2);
    barBind(*c2);

    system("PAUSE");
};
```

the Output is:

[image]